# How to escape overflow: hidden with only one element?

Tags: html, css

Before you mark this as duplicate, read this:
I have a menu (container) with an absolute position, the overflow-y is set to scroll, and overflow-x is hidden. I also have tooltips when you hover on parts of the menu, and some of them overflow beyond the menu. For some reason the tooltips will never display beyond the container, and i have tried position absolute, and z-index, and even overflow-x:visible. None of this works. For example:

CSS:

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='tooltip'></div>
</div>
```

```
.tooltip {
position:absolute;
left:-5px;
top:0;
width:10px;
height:10px;
background-color:black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='menu'>
<div class='tooltip'></div>
</div>
```

and the tooltip div wont ever display beyond the menu. I am unable to change position on menu or tooltip, as they need to be relative to any other tooltips and menus. I have a working jsfiddle of this game: https://jsfiddle.net/fm6zrtuq/
all you need to do is press the gear icon in the top right and hover over the icon with the trophy and you can see what i really mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I've understood you want to achieve something like this:

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;

}
.menu:hover .tooltip {
left: 5px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='tooltip'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: close to, but i would like to be able to keep absolute position on all classes, as there are more than on tooltip that rely on each other to determine where they need to be positioned, and i tried this, but the tooltip still wouldnt show on my code. i can provide a jsfiddle if you want to look at it all

Comment: try to wrap it inside another `div` and give the wrapper the specified size and the `.menu` `height: 100%`.

Comment: i tried this, and i wont allow the div that i wrapped it in to overflow. Kinda sad, but it gives me the idea of just not allowing scroll and instead making different pages. Thanks for all the help but i think im going to go this route instead as it requires less debugging. I will mark your answer as the answer however, because it clearly works for other situations, just incase someone else stumbles across this and needs and asnwer.